# Setting up iOS device / simulator to retrieve en_150 as locale

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, internationalization, nslocale

How do iOS apps evaluate to a specific Locale?

Regarding Apple Docs, it follows standardized way (CLDR) with apple customized fallback strategies.

In Swift, I'm trying to figure out how `Locale.current.identifier` or Objective-C equivalent specifically output:

- en
- en_150
- es
- ...

(Without having a region designator)

**How do I configure the simulator or device to achieve this?**

What else influences `Locale.current`?

- preferred language(s) (also the order)
- selected region
- supported languages from your app
- (some other settings like calendar, phonebook collation) these are suffixed with an @

Interesting sources:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html

https://opensource.apple.com/source/ICU/ICU-57131.0.1/icuSources/common/unicode/ualoc.h.auto.html

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/71383

Comment: You are not going to get just `en`. You will get, for example, `en_US` or whatever country based on the selected region.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I do have backend logs from devices around the globe without having a region. That's why I'm asking.